# cant figure it out how to get the print avoiding the error that close the programm

Tags: python, api, wikipedia

I'm trying to avoid the error that I get when I run Wikipedia API and I have a Disambiguation content to search, normally would get only the similar Wikipedia titles, but now I'm getting this exception `wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError(title, may_refer_to)`,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nicolas/Desktop/copia 2.py", line 303, in <module>
    output1 =(wikipedia.summary(hulk, sentences=2))
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/wikipedia/util.py", line 28, in __call__
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/wikipedia/wikipedia.py", line 231, in summary
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/wikipedia/wikipedia.py", line 276, in page
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/wikipedia/wikipedia.py", line 299, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/wikipedia/wikipedia.py", line 393, in __load
wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError: "Hulk" may refer to: 
Hulk (comics)
Hulk (film)
Hulk (video game)
Hulk Hogan
Antonio Salazar (footballer)
Hulk (footballer)
Johannes Frederik Hulk
Hulk (ship type)
Hulk (medieval ship type)
Prison hulk
De Hulk
The Incredible Hulk (disambiguation)
```

and this stops the program , I would like to avoid the error and get only the print of different titles like "Hulk (comics) (the full list)

Comment: Please show a [mcve] which causes this error.

Comment: Could you give an example code and not just the error?

Answer (score 2):

The [Wikipedia API quickstart document](http://wikipedia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) has a suggestion: catch the exception and extract the text you need:

```
try:
    mercury = wikipedia.summary("Mercury")
except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
    print e.options

[u'Mercury (mythology)', u'Mercury (planet)', u'Mercury (element)', u'Mercury, Nevada', ...]
```

Comment: this works very thanks , sorry if i didnt share any code from which understand the problem( i tought i've done it)